# Como usar um seletor de texto no html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como eu posso fazer um seletor de texto dentro do HTML de forma que eu possa ter opções quando determinado texto dentro de uma tag p, por exemplo, for selecionado?

Comment: Cara sua pergunta está um pouco confuza. Vc quer clipar na palavra "X" dentro de uma tag P e quer que alguma coisa mude é isso? Ou vc que achar a tag P que tem a palavra "X" dentro e colocar um classe nela?

Comment: Opa, tipo, eu quero selecionar (com o mouse) umas 3 palavras consecutivas e quando isso acontecer, quero mostrar possíveis ações a usuário. Entende?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para pegar o texto selecionado vc usa a função `getSelection()`:

Veja o exemplo:

```js
$('p').mouseup(function(){
    var range = window.getSelection();
    alert(range);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Como eu posso fazer um seletor de texto dentro do HTML de forma que eu possa ter opções quando determinado texto dentro de uma tag p, por exemplo, for selecionado?</p>
```

> [Referência da função getSelection()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection)

Comment: Tomei a liberdade de editar a sua resposta para embutir um código executável.

Comment: @lazyFox eu vi, ficou bom, não sei ainda como criar respostas executáveis assim, muito obrigado.

Comment: Só muitos obrigados manos

Comment: Quando for editar pressione `CTRL` + `M`. Se não funcionar na janela de edição veja o icone á direita da imagem

Answer (score 2):

Você pode designar uma função para ser executada quando um evento ocorrer no elemento.

O evento para quando um texto for selecionado na tag, seria o evento `onSelect`.

Por exemplo, você quer que o texto selecionado apareça no console, então você faria algo como:

```
<p onselect="funcao()">(conteúdo aqui)</p>

<script>function funcao() { alert('Selecionou um texto'); }</script>
```

E sobre a função receber dados de um input, acredito que esse input deve ser capturado na função que o evento chama.

Answer (score -1):

Não sei se é exatamente o que você quer, mas você pode deixar a `textarea` customizada utilizando `tinyMCE`.

O [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/) é um textárea com freatures editáveis. Você pode deixar desde só negrito e itálico, até a possibilidade de visualizar o código html sendo gerado por trás, entre outros. Uso há algum tempo, é muito bom.